# YamlDotNet deserialize integer as numeric not as string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, yamldotnet

I need to convert a **yaml file** to **json format** for validating it against a **json schema**.
So I use *yamldotnet* to read the yaml file and *json.net* to serialize it into a string in json format.
Unfortunately, after that, **all numeric values are converted to string** and validation goes wrong.

How can I avoid that?

Here is the code I use:

```
var t = File.ReadAllText(src);
var d = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Deserializer();
var sr = new StringReader(t);
var o = d.Deserialize(sr);
var s = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
s.Serialize(sw, o);
txt = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("JSON Output: {0}", txt);
```

Comment: Can you post here your `d` object's properties?

Comment: d's properties are:
10 NodeDeserializers
5 TypeResolvers
and as Non-Public members:
backwardsCompatibleConfiguration
and valueDeserializer of type *DefaultContainersNodeTypeResolver*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around this by forcing the data types with tags in the source YAML e.g.

```
myObject:
  myIntValue: !!int 5
  myBoolValue: !!bool true
  myStringValue: hi there
```

It's not ideal, but can be a useful trick.

Comment: Great, I was not aware of that feature